# How to uninstall a .ps1 file installed with Powershell

Tags: powershell, plugins, nuget

So as a solution to particular issue, I installed The Azure Artifacts Credential Provider using the following command:

`iex "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.ps1) }"`

This was listed as a possible fix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com)

It didn't fix my issue, and I was wondering how to uninstall this. I don't see it show up in Apps and Features.  It looks to have shown up in %userprofile%/.nuget/plugins.

Just looking to undo what I've done. I'm looking for the specific command to remove this.

Comment: you need to look at the contents of the ps1 file, and figure out manually how to undo whatever it did. There's no systematic way to undo what a powershell script changes. If you're lucky, the script might have a `-Uninstall` option, but that's entirely up to the author of the ps1 file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, its a bad idea to execute powershell scripts even from trusted sources if you dont understand what it does - take time to read through the script and figure out whats going on before you run it.

The code seems quite well documented, and outputs whats its doing to the console - thats your easiest way of uninstalling is to watch what it does and reverse the changes. (Next time try using `Start-Transcript` *before* executing a script for it to save the output to a file for later review)

From a quick scan of the code, it seems like its just downloading nuget packages to your `$env:UserProfile` folder. You can just move those folders outside the nuget folder so they are no longer available.

To find the folders - search the script for the lines with `.zip` to find the package names - then search your `$env:UserProfile` folder for those names (without the `.zip` extension). I would suggest you just cut/paste the folders to another location so you can undo you uninstall if necessary by puting the files back, once your happy it all works then delete the files you moved.